# Perl compare individual elements of two arrays

Tags: perl, loops

I have two files with two columns each:

```
FILE1

A   B

1   #

2   @

3   !

4   %

5   %

FILE 2

A   B

3   # 

4   !

2   &

1   %

5   ^
```

The Perl script must compare column A in both both files, and only if they are equal, column B of FIlE 2 must be printed

So far I have the following code but all I get is an infinite loop with # from column B

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

print "enter site:"."\n";
chomp(my $s = <>);

print "enter protein:"."\n";
chomp(my $p = <>);

open( FILE, "<  $s" ) or die;
open( OUT, "> PSP.txt" ) or die;
open( FILE2, "< $p" ) or die;

my @firstcol;
my @secondcol;
my @thirdcol;

while ( <FILE> )
{
        next if $. <2;
        chomp;
        my @cols = split;
        push @firstcol, $cols[0];
        push @secondcol, $cols[1]."\t"."\t".$cols[3]."\t"."\t"."\t"."N\/A"."\n";
}

my @firstcol2;
my @secondcol2;
my @thirdcol2;

while ( <FILE2> )
{
        next if $. <2;

        my @cols2 = split(/\t/, $_);
        push @firstcol2, $cols2[0];
        push @secondcol2, $cols2[4]."\n";
}

my $size = @firstcol;
my $size2 = @firstcol2;


for (my $i = 0; $i <= @firstcol ; $i++) {
                for (my $j = 0; $j <= @firstcol2; $j++)  {
                if ( $firstcol[$i] eq $firstcol2[$j] )
                {
                        print $secondcol2[$i];
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my (@first, @second);
while(<first>){
    chomp;
    my $foo = split / /, $_;
    push @first , $foo;
}

while(<second>){
    chomp;
    my $bar = split / / , $_;
    push @second, $bar;
}

my %first = @first;
my %second = @second;
```

Build a hash of the first file as %first and second file as %second with first column as key and second column as value.

```
for(keys %first)
{
    print $second{$_} if exists $second{$_}
}
```

I couldn't check it as I am on mobile. hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Beware of lost rows where two of the left values are the same, also hash's don't generate in order.

Comment: can someone elaborate :)

Comment: Sure - when you add a key/value pair to a hash, if the key was there already, the new value replaces the old one. If there are repeated values in `@first`, then the item in `@second` that paired with the first duplicate value in `@first` will disappear because it's been overwritten by the second key/value pair with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that column A is ordered and that you actually want to compare the first entry in File 1 to the first entry in File 2, and so on.

If that's true, you have nested loop that you don't need.  Simplify your last while as such:

```
for my $i (0..$#firstcol) {
    if ( $firstcol[$i] eq $firstcol2[$i] )
    {
        print $secondcol2[$i];
    }
}
```

Also, if you're at all concerned about the files being of different length, then you can adjust the loop:

```
use List::Util qw(min);

for my $i (0..min($#firstcol, $#firstcol2)) {
```

*Additional Note:* You aren't chomping your data in the second file loop `while ( <FILE2> )`.  That might introduce a bug later.

Comment: I made the changes but now I get a blank output.
for (my $i = 0; $i <= @firstcol ; $i++) {
if ( @firstcol[$i] eq  @firstcol2[$i] )
    {
                    print $secondcol2[$i];
                        }
                }

Comment: After your `while(<FILE2>)` loop, verify that your data is set as you expect.  `use Data::Dump; dd \@secondcol2;`.  Most likely `@secondcol2` is empty or something, so you likely need to fix something in the setting up of your data.

Comment: Also, `for (my $i = 0; $i <= @firstcol ; $i++)` isn't completely right.  If you MUST use c style looping, then you need to change your test to `$i < @firstcol` or `$i <= $#firstcol`.  Or even better, just use a loop like I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: To confirm that the rest of your loop is correct, change your print statement to `print "Matches row $i, as $firstcol[$i]\n";`  Which for the data you have represented, should match for `A` and `5`

Comment: I tried for my $i(0..$#firstcol) {
        if ( $firstcol[$i] eq  $firstcol2[$i] )
                {
                    print "testtest";
                    }
                }

Comment: but I still get a blank output

Comment: Then you need to output more debugging information.  Try this loop: `for my $i (0..$#firstcol) { print "$i, '$firstcol[$i]', '$firstcol2[$i]'\n"; }`  If you see something that looks wrong, then you'll have to trace back and figure out why it does.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are called `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` the next:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Path::Class;

my $files;
@{$files->{$_}} = map { [split /\s+/] } grep { !/^\s*$/ } file("file$_.txt")->slurp for (1..2);
for my $line1 (@{$files->{1}}) {
    my $line2 = shift @{$files->{2}};
    say $line2->[1] if ($line1->[0] eq $line2->[0]);
}
```

prints:

```
B
^
```

equals in column1 only the lines `A` and `5`

without the CPAN modules - produces the same result

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $files;
@{$files->{$_}} = map { [split /\s+/] } grep { !/^\s*$/ } do { local(@ARGV)="file$_.txt";<> } for (1..2);
for my $line1 (@{$files->{1}}) {
    my $line2 = shift @{$files->{2}};
    print $line2->[1],"\n" if ($line1->[0] eq $line2->[0]);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without the modules?

Comment: @user3357980 sure - see the edit - but what you have againist the modules? or this is an homework?

Comment: I just can't download them onto the mac :/

Comment: @user3357980 im on mac too.. if you don't have admin rights, you can install `local::lib` or `perlbrew`.

Comment: Perlbrew (though you need to install Xcode to use it) is fantastic, and keeps you from having to modify the system Perl. Definitely use it!